# Problem about a family of holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Given the family
$$
\mathscr{F}=\{f:D\to D : f\text{ holomorphic and } f'(0)=1/2\},
$$
I have to prove that there is a function $g\in\mathscr{F}$ so that:

$$|g(0)|=\sup\limits_{f\in\mathscr{F}}|f(0)|$$

I don't know how to start. Can someone give me a hint? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $\mathscr{F}$ is a normal family.